# Skype bot subscriber limit

Tags: botframework, skype

Is there a limit with number of subscribers who can communicate with a skype bot.
That is, will it be restricted for 1000(say) users or so to communicate with a single bot

Answer (score 1):

If your bot has not been approved/published there is a limit of 100 contacts.  There is no limit for bots that have been approved.